# jQuery append is not working when using load before

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, append, preventdefault

Append function is not working when using it after the load function.

```
$('section article a').on('click',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).attr('class');
    $('article[id='+id+']').load( 'articles/'+id+'.html' );

    $('article[id='+id+']').append( "<strong> Where am I?<br/>StackOverflow HELP !!!</strong>" );   //This is NOT appended

});
```

Any idea ?

Comment: append might be called before load() finishes. Try using load with the callback function which would call append. load( url, [data], [callback] ) https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: suggestion:  instead of using the class attribute use a data- property.  Like data-articleid to set your linked article id.  This will protect you should something add css classes to your link. Also, since id's are unique you can just do a $('#'+id) selector or even $('article#'+id) if that makes you feel safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wait until your `load` finish then use `append()` instead:

```
$('article[id='+id+']').load( 'articles/'+id+'.html', function() {
    $('article[id='+id+']').append( "<strong> Where am I?<br/>StackOverflow HELP !!!</strong>" ); 
});
```

Also you can just use `$('#'+id)` instead of `$('article[id='+id+']')` since `id` is unique.

Comment: I need to wait 11 min to accept your answer but ACCEPTED ! PERFECT !

Comment: +1 You could also use `$(this).append()` inside the load callback as there's no change of scope ;)